# Zingchart | Half donut chart

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

Any ideas for hiding the unused half in the 180º pie charts? As you can see in the image I attached, it still uses the same height as a 360° pizza chart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc9aL.png)

I have been using these configs:

```
type: "pie", 
scaleR: {
   aperture: 180,
},
plot: {
   refAngle: 180,
   slice: "40%"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can play around with offsetY on plot and sizing the pie via sizeFactor to hide the unused half in the 180º pie charts. Please use this [demo](https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/create/CZQOPF41) for reference.

**NB**: This is not flexible if the container dimension changes.
[image]